# Registering all functions that implement an interface and allowing a passed-in context to invoke the applicable function (command)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Lambda function that processes incoming messages and sends emails based on an enum `type` property in the message. I have N number of "handlers", one per `type`, and this number grows from time to time. I could register them in a simple object or Map, but I'd prefer to register them all automatically in a store the same way we'd register models in an ORM, for example:

```
[models/Order.js]
module.exports = Sequelize.define('Order', {properties...methods...etc});

[models/LineItem.js]
module.exports = Sequelize.define('LineItem', {properties...methods...etc});
```

and then anywhere we want to access our models, we'd be able to grab `Sequelize.models.Order` or even generically `Sequelize.models[type]`.

This is the sort of typical parent-child OOP interface that I'd know how to handle in PHP via interfaces and an app-wide class registry or factory of "commands" for a given domain. In node it's a little less clear how to get this with less boilerplate code, and I seem to run into this problem often. Here's what I have working now, simplified for clarity:

**app.js**

```
// Configure handlers.
const handlers = require(path.join(__dirname, 'handler/index.js'));

exports.lambda = async (event, context) => {

    ...

    // Parse message.
    const msg = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);

    // Get handler.
    const handler = handlers.get(msg.type);
    if (!handler) throw new Error(`Unknown type ${msg.type}.`);

    // Run handler.
    await handler.handle(msg, emailParams, vars);

    ...
};
```

**handler/index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = new Map();

fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname)).forEach(file => {
    if (file !== 'index.js') {
        const handler = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
        module.exports.set(handler.type, handler);
    }
});
```

**handler/SendInvoice.js** (one example of a "handler")

```
module.exports = {
    type: 'SEND_INVOICE',
    handle: async (msg, emailParams, vars) => {

        // Configure email.
        emailParams.Destination.ToAddresses = [msg.email];
        emailParams.Message.Subject.Data = `Invoice #${msg.invoiceNum}`;

        // Set variables.
        vars.email = msg.email;
        vars.invoiceNum = msg.invoiceNum;
        vars.salespersonName = msg.salespersonName;
        vars.salespersonEmail = msg.salespersonEmail;
    },
    tpl: `
        <mjml>
            <mj-body background-color="#ffffff">
                <mj-section>
                    <mj-column>
                        ...msg content...
                    </mj-column>
                </mj-section>
            </mj-body>
        </mjml>
    `,
};
```

I'm bothered that I seem to have to re-invent this quite often, and that I don't have a clear picture of the "best" way to implement. Do I module.export a definition? Or should the module be responsible for registering itself? I could extend the prototype of a parent "handler" class (or use ES6 classes) but that doesn't give me a *registry* of commands to pull from. If it does register itself, can I lazy-load it the way I can PHP classes or must I write boilerplate code to load all files in a folder everywhere I do this kind of thing? I suppose this is the command pattern, but the question remains of where/how to store the registry of commands in javascript?

You can see I'm perplexed. Thanks for any insight and clarity!